# selecting divs within a same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery conundrum. can some one help me select the appropriate div to scroll to. Right now it works for the first one but others just dont work. Here is code : https://jsfiddle.net/fwm4ot69/

Here is the JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //hide answers or hide in css
    $('.acc_content').hide();
    $('.acctitle').click(function() {
        //show this answer
        $(this).next().slideToggle('1000');
        //Hide the other panels
        $(".acc_content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
        $.scrollTo($(this), 1000);
    });
});
```

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js">
    </script>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="acctitle">
            <h3>What is This?</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="acc_content">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
            ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
            and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not
            only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
            remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
            with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
            passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="acctitle">
            <h3>What is This?</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="acc_content">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
            ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
            and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not
            only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
            remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
            with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
            passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="acctitle">
            <h3>What is This?</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="acc_content">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
            ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
            and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not
            only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
            remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
            with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
            passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

What can i do to make the screen start on the selected question, esp on a mobile device?

THanks
```

Comment: first, specify how you're accessing a page with one selected... like www.domain.com/question1 or www.domain.com?q=1 or some such. Then show how you're generating html. You can give an ID or class to any element, so it would be logical to assign a class by get vars or uri segments, then in js you just check for that element's class $('.selected').length and then scroll to it on load $.scrollTo($('.selected').offset().top, 1000); it would help to see your html too. fiddles are ok here, so editing may not be necessary, but not everyone will follow the links

Comment: I am trying to start the page on the clicked question

Comment: pages don't start on clicked anything. they have to know to select something so inbound links have to have some kind of identifier. ?q=1, /question/1, #question1, etc. How are you doing it currently?

Comment: atm, i dont know, i tried putting a href on html so that, no coding is required, but they break here and there. I am trying         $.scrollTo($(this), 1000); in my code but this is just selecting the first question. How do i code to select the div that is being selected so that the code works to whatever question is being selected?

Comment: Aah, gotcha. I think I know what you're saying now. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first, your fiddle shows a console error. $.scrollTo is not a function. Maybe you didn't import a library or that could just be due to it not being in the fiddle libs? Either way...

You can change `$.scrollTo($(this), 1000);` to this:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 1000);
```

If you `console.log($(this).offset().top)` you will see that this is returning a valid offset. This will only jump to the section if the page is long enough to scroll., and it will only scroll as far as the bottom of the page.

Now, your question seems to ask how to jump to a question on page load. If that's the case you might try the simple way...

html:

```
<div class="acctitle" id="question-1">
   <h3>What is This?</h3>
</div>
```

Then you can just access by url: `www.somedomain.com#question-1`
Which will anchor to that ID. But in js you can add:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash)
    {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top}, 1000, function(){
            $(window.location.hash).next().slideDown(1000);
        });
    }
});
```

which should load the page with the requested question expanded. First it will scroll, then expand.

If this isn't want you were looking for let me know.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I used $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 1000); on my code. This works. But only when i remove the slide up code. I think the problem is when the "p" elements slide up it scrolls the page up again resulting in the contents in the middle of the page. This is not a problem on a pc or tablet but on the mobile devices it created a problem, because the question is above the page and the screen has answers covering from top to bottom. thinking to restructure code so it first slides up the content then goes to the appropriate question. what do u think?

Comment: Also. I am not looking to reload the page eachtime. Anyway I am just a designer but it's bugging me. I dont understand lot of code. So thanks again for help.

Comment: Right, you see how in the bottom example I do the scrollTop{...}, 1000, function(){} - that function is the callback. It follows after the duration, which is the 1000. So you can first slide up all the elements, which you do with the  .not() line. So you can change slideUp('fast') to slideUp('fast', function(){ ... }) and within that callback you then tell it to slide down the selected element. That way it will condense the dom, then scroll to the new element, then expand. Should work out the calculation issues of running it all outside callbacks